# ItemSource Binding on Custom Picker in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Custom Control, that consists of a Label and a Custom Picker. I need to bind the values to the ItemSource property in Xaml. This is what I have tried so far, but there is'nt any values showing in the picker.
Edit 04/10/2017 : I have upload a sample project to github which has the custom control: https://github.com/libin85/BindablePicker
This is the CustomControl Xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WoolQ.Core.Controls;assembly=WoolQ.Core" 
x:Class="WoolQ.Core.Controls.CustomLabelWithPicker">
<Grid x:Name="grid" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:RoundedFrame OutlineColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Label x:Name="title" Text="" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,5,5,0" Style="{StaticResource CustomConrtolLabelStyle}" />
    <controls:BorderlessPicker x:Name="pickerValue" Title="_" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource CustomConrtolPickerStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}">
    </controls:BorderlessPicker>
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind I have:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemSource), typeof(List<string>), typeof(CustomLabelWithPicker), null);

    public List<string> ItemSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<string>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == nameof(ItemSource))
        {
            this.pickerValue.Items.Clear();
            if (ItemSource != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in ItemSource)
                {
                    this.pickerValue.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally in my View, I bind the Itemsource with a List like this.

```
<controls:CustomLabelWithPicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
LabelText="Bin Codes" ItemSource="{Binding BinCodes}"/>
```

But I dont see any values binded. Appreciate your help

Comment: perhaps the BindingContext for CustomLabelWithPicker is not set in the consumer view model, which is why it is unable to find the ItemsSource binding

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your custom picker:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomPicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnItemsSourceChanged);

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var picker = (CustomPicker)bindable;
            picker.ItemsSource = (IList)newValue;
        }
```

Comment: Cant resolve DisplayProperty() on picker @Ziyad Godil

Comment: and moreover we have a bindable picker. so do we need all that code?

Comment: is OnPropertyChanged method call in your code when your itemsource changed?

Comment: When we have Binding defined in Xaml , we dont need to explicity call anything right

Comment: put debug point in OnPropertyChanged method and check, Is that value get in ItemSource property?

Comment: I think you need to put this line "base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);" last in OnPropertyChanged method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155818/discussion-between-ziyad-godil-and-libin-joseph).